# R how to split a single column into a specified number of pieces

Tags: r

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('x: 1', 'y: 2'))
```

I would like to split 'col1' by the colon and store each token in a separate column. The following is how the output should look like:

col1 , col2

x , 1

y , 2

the line below is doing the split **but how to store each token in it's own column:**

```
df %>% mutate(x = str_split(col1,': ',2))
```

Comment: It is not clear how to store each token in it's own column.

Comment: What's not clear?  Almost all the answers there show how to do that.

Comment: @ronencozen Try e.g. `splitstackshape::cSplit(df, 1, ":")`, which might need `install.packages("splitstackshape")` before.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but i am looking for an elegant solution, could be that i will end up using tidyr::separate, and simply ignore the warning, in the case of more than two tokens.

Comment: In base R - `strcapture("([a-z]+): (\\d+)", as.character(df$col1), data.frame(col1 = character(), col2 = integer()))`

Comment: Interesting approach, i guess it could turn into a more generic one by adapting the patterns, thank you!